# Pyspark Dataframe count taking too long

Tags: pyspark

So we have a Pyspark Dataframe which has around 25k records. We are trying to perform a count/empty check on this and it is taking too long. We tried,

1. df.count()
2. df.rdd.isEmpty()
3. len(df.head(1))==0
4. Converted to Pandas and tried pandas_df.empty()
5. Tried the arrow option
6. df.cache() and df.persist() before the counts
7. df.repartition(n)
8. Tried writing the df to DBFS, but writing is also taking quite a long time(cancelled after 20 mins)

Could you please help us on what we are doing wrong.

Note : There are no duplicate values in df and we have done multiple joins to form the df

Comment: Could you add the output of `df.explain()`? It could be that there are many heavy transformations before the count.

Answer (score 3):

Without looking at the `df.explain()` it's challenging to know specifically the issue but it certainly seems like you have *could* have a [skewed data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) set.
(Skew usually is represented in the Spark UI with 1 executor taking a lot longer than the other partitions to finish.) If you on a recent version of spark there are [tools](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html) to help with this out of the box:

> ```
> spark.sql.adaptive.enabled  = true
> spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled = true
> ```

Count is not taking too long. It's taking the time it needs to, to complete what you asked spark to do.  To refine what it's doing you should do things you are likely already doing, filter the data first before joining so only critical data is being transferred to the joins.  Reviewing your data for Skew, and programming around it, **if you can't use adaptive query**.

**Convince yourself this is a data issue.**  Limit your source [data/tables] to 1000 or 10000 records and see if it runs fast.  Then one at a time, remove the limit from only one [table/data source] (and apply limit to all others) and find the table that is the source of your problem.  Then study the [table/data source] and figure out how you can work around the issue.(**If** you can't use adaptive query to fix the issue.)

(Finally If you are using hive tables, you should make sure the [table stats](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/performance-tuning/content/hive_generate_hive_statistics.html) are up to date.)

> ANALYZE TABLE mytable COMPUTE STATISTICS;

Comment: So here the dataframe is just having 24k records and df.explain() is pretty big. Found out that withColumn is creating long time. But after fixing that too, through databricks it is running fast, but through ADF it is gettinng timed out. Is there any particular reason why from ADF Pipeline this is timing-out

Comment: If the explain is pretty big it's not a simple count and this accounts for time it would take.  And for good advice I still suggest posting it.

Comment: ADF could be using 'commodity' storage and writing/reading is the biggest bottleneck.  Have you considered `approx_count` it will respond with a estimate and that might be enough.  If you are able to run this on Databricks, then you maybe able to extrapolate an estimate **if you took a valid sample. ** If you did you could look at the file size of your data, and create a ratio to the complete data set.  This would also give you an approximation of the count.